# AWS SAM build use container without cleaning

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

Currently, building AWS SAM is really slow.

```
sam build --use-container
```

that prevent me from testing out small changes on code and not on the dependencies.

Is there away that sam build will only copy the source and do not perform any kind of clean/reinstall of dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution supported by AWS could be using of Dependencies Layer with detail to be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/).

Comment: Useful, but it still seems to me more like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know about the `--skip-pull-image` option that allows you to avoid pulling the container image on rebuild.

Otherwise, looking in the [source](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/v0.12.0/samcli/lib/build/app_builder.py#L40) [code](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-builders/blob/v0.2.0/aws_lambda_builders/builder.py#L19) and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html), there does not [appear](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-builders/blob/v0.2.0/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/nodejs_npm/workflow.py#L62) to be any support for not rebuilding the dependencies.

Note that in the [DESIGN.md](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-builders/blob/v0.2.0/DESIGN.md) is suggested how a user could perhaps write their own "plugin" to implement a different "workflow":

> ... each language-specific piece acts almost like a plugin, its its own self contained directory. Someone could develop their own "package" with the structure

This could help to find a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I did use the --skip-pull-image. However it seems to be slow in the process of running "npm install" which is fine if we need to build the dependencies. But there are many cases that we only need to change a small portion in the code to test out, and currently the whole building process is trigger which is unnecessary and slow. I will look into the source code to see if there is any kind of temp solution. Thanks for the quick reply and useful links!

Comment: I have updated above with corrected refs to the source code after I looked through [aws-lambda-builders](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-builders), which points perhaps to the way forward of implementing a workaround?